# Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes

Tags: git

I want to remove some files/ folder from git history according to [git documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository), but it fails due to `unstaged changes`. It is not clear to me what unstaged changes there could be as i did  `git add --all` , commit & push before. note that the to-be-deleted folder `somefolder/` does not exist in HEAD anymore. It was moved on earlier commits, but it's old versions need to be purged from the repo.

```sh
~$ git add --all
~$ git commit -m "trying to fix 'Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes'"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
~$ git push
Everything up-to-date
~$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
~$ git filter-branch --force --index-filter   "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch somefolder/"   --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.
~$
```

how do i fix this so i can run the last command successfully?

Comment: What's the output of `git status`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure to use the latest Git (2.26), as [there was a bug in older Git versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9246622/6309) regarding [git filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

Second, you might want to [clone your repo as a bare repository, and do the filtering there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56841045/6309). That would prevent any unstaged changes, since a bare repository has no working tree.

But thrid, don't use the [obsolete BFG or `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309) for this.
Use new tool [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (directly in your regular local repository, although a backup is always a good idea before those kind of filtering)

Use a [path filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES):

```
git filter-repo --path somefolder/ --invert-paths
```

That will remove `somefolder/` from the Git repository history.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I had some trouble like `git-filter-repo` requiring the dash before `filter`, and subsequent pushing got rejected `because the remote contains work that you do`. i could fix that with the `--force` flag. however i finally managed to remove that specific folder from the git history. 
I also got `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories` when pulling the changes to my original local repo. will fix that, too....